# IF ARRAY Formula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to find the `SUM` of a multipart `IF` statement using a separate spreadsheet:

```
=SUM(IF(AND([Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$7:$B$348="APPL*", C15=[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$4:$BG$4),[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$I$7:$J$348))
```

**NOTE: C15 = "A1"**

I've tried breaking this formula down into these two separate parts:

```
=IF(C15=[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$4:$BG$4,TRUE)
```

and

```
=IF([Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$7:$B$348 = "APPL*",TRUE)
```

However, these all fail out.

How can you find a single output using two criteria such as a column head and a row header?

Here is an image of what I'm working with. I need to sum all of the numbers met by the criteria from the grid by using the Column header and Row header.

Comment: Your sum area is not the same number of columns as the headers.  Also look into SUMPRODUCT() it will work well with this, but only it the sum area is the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments one must have uniform output to input ranges; same number of rows as the row headers and same number of columns as the column headers.

This will then find where the two intersect and sum the corresponding intersections.

With Array formula on cannot use `AND()` or `OR()` functions.  Use `*` or `+` respectively to accomplish the same thing.

So something like:

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A12=B15)*(B1:K1=B16),B2:K12))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

But one can do the same with SUMPRODUCT() without the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12=B15)*(B1:K1=B16),B2:K12)
```

SUMPRODUCT does not need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter but the normal entry method.  It is still an array type formula.

[image]

---

Now to the second part IF/SUMPRODUCT do not use wild cards so you will need to use SEARCH() which will allow the use of wildcards.

```
=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("APPL*",[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$7:$B$348)))*(C15=[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$4:$BG$4),[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$7:$BG$348))
```

The SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("APPL*",[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$7:$B$348)))*(C15=[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$4:$BG$4),[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$7:$BG$348)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, This has helped a lot. I am running into issue with my Wildcard as well though... Unfortunately my Row Headers are similar but not the same so a wildcard is necessary.                                        =SUMPRODUCT(('[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$A$348="Appling*")*('[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$4:$AM$4=C15),'[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$7:$AM$348)

Comment: how would you add this "ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" to the SUMPRODUCT formula?  Here's what I Have and my returned result is "0".                                           =SUMPRODUCT(('[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$A$348=(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Appling*",'[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$7:$A$348))))*('[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$4:$AM$4=C15),'[Doc.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$7:$AM$348)